# nservicebus messages vanished

Tags: azure, queue, nservicebus

NserviceBus version: 6.0.0.0
Use AzureStorageQueueTransport

All messages should be sent to a queue in Azure storage queue,

We have huge amount of messages send to queue so another app can pick up to process.

Occasionally, there are some messages (let's say 0.01% of total messages) that are created, serialized, but it never reach to azure storage queue.

So those messages are vanished without any exception or error.

Comment: Please provide more specifics, [Minimum Verifiable Result](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What kind of messages are you losing? How can you tell they are not there?

Comment: @user9665486 messages that are failing to be dispatched would at least have a [log entry](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/logging/). Check that first. Make sure loggign is not disabled.

Comment: If messages are sent from within  handlers, send operation will be retried until incoming message moved to an error queue with a reason. If sending is done outside of handler, operation will throw an exception that would propagate into your code. More on this in [documentation](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/messaging/send-a-message). And last, but not the least, a reproduced issue with working code shared on GitHub or elsewhere will help immensly to  see what are you doing. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The package CacheManager.Core with version 1.0.1 could not be found in `C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\`. Run a NuGet package restore to download the package.

but my project is in D: drive. all of other packages are fine except error for this package. 
here is snapshoot of packages.config

`<packages>
  <package id="CacheManager.Core" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="3.3.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Castle.Windsor" version="3.3.0" targetFramework="net462" />...`

Actually, the packages are in both mentioned `C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\`  and in project file location